# Dell XPS 14Z (L412z) 4 beeps

Tags: memory, dell-xps

I have a Dell XPS 14z L412z I just recently got 4 beeps, which means RAM fail read/write. I have two RAM slots; I have bought new RAM then switched them out but there are still 4 beeps.

I also tried putting RAM in one slot 1 and leaving the slot 2 empty. Then I tried putting RAM in slot 2 leaving slot 1 empty. Still 4 beeps. If I start up the computer without RAM I get 2 beeps. I feel as if the RAM slots aren't the problem. It makes no sense that both slots would randomly stop working. Also since it switches to 2 beeps. It knows when the RAM is in there or not.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like the memory controller has gone bad, if its part of the cpu you could try another cpu if its not cost prohibitive.

Comment: the cpu is integrated into the laptop motherboard :( anything I can do to fix it